# For finding Eulerian Circuit, storage of state of edge being visited or not

Tags: arrays, graph-theory, edges

There is a graph of vertex set V, such that |V| >= 100000 and edge set E, such that |E|<= 200000. Am am trying to traversing Eulerian Circuit in the graph. For that, I need to store whether a particular edge is visited or not? I usually use 2D array for that, but due to big size of |V| I can't use arrays. What should I use properly to store the state of the edge being visited or not, efficiently?

Comment: Which language are you coding in? If it has some hashset/set you can use that.

Comment: I am using c++, it does have set/map. But it would be very inefficient to use them as the number of edges increases.

Comment: How are you storing your graph? As an adjacency list with `vector<int>[]` or `vector<vector<int>>` or some other way?

Comment: I am using vector<int>[]. I think I found the answer. I can store each edge in a vector<pair<int, int> >, this will give each edge and a visited array for the edges. This works.